# Case Study Series

Tags: discussion, on-topic, case-study

As discussed [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/worldbuilders-general-chat) and based on Tim B's [recent post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3043/case-studies-on-or-off-topic) , I'd like us to have a series of case studies, where various users of the site post their five top-rated questions (or any five questions of their own they think would be most interesting), self-evaluate, then allow the rest of the community to debate whether or not these questions are or should be on-topic. The point of this is to help come to a consensus of what should be on or off-topic for this site, so that going forward we can present a unified front of moderation and guidance to new users, and preserve the integrity of the site as it makes the transition of graduation.

This post will serve as an FYI, and as a reference to each post as it is posted. I've volunteered myself to go next, on Monday the 8th; I was thinking after this, future posts would be spaced out to every other day.

If anyone wants to volunteer, let me know and we can get it scheduled. I know a few of you have already shown interest, just let me know (here or in chat) what day you want to go and I'll fill it in.

Please do let me know if you want to contribute, and please wait your turn; the last thing we want is to be flooded with case studies no one evaluates.

**Posts:**

1. [February 5 - Tim B](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3043/case-studies-on-or-off-topic)
2. [February 8 - Daaaah Whoosh](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/case-study-2-daaaah-whoosh)
3. [February 10 - James](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3093/case-study-3-james)
4. [February 15 - overactor](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3145/case-study-4-overactor)
5. [February 16 - Green](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3168/case-studies-greens-highest-viewed-questions)
6. [February 18 - HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3200/case-study-6-hde-226868?lq=1)
7. [February 20 - Aify](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3225/case-study-7-aify)
8. [Pavel Janicek](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/case-study-pavel-janicek)
9. [Monica Cellio](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3261/case-study-monica-cellio)

**Remaining volunteers:**

- ArtOfCode

**Dates:**

- February 10 - James
- February 12 - ArtOfCode
- February 14 - overactor
- February 16 - Green
- February 18 - HDE 226868
- February 20 - Aify
- February 22 - Monica Cellio
- February 24 - Pavel Janicek

---

With the above volunteers, we have quite some questions to review. If you want to volunteer yourself, you can add a comment, below. But for the moment, the above should be sufficient.

Comment: I'd like to propose that, at the end of each case study (no fixed time limit, but when discussion seems to have died down), the initiator post a summary answer, drawn from all the others, so that in the future we can easily see what the community consensus was for each case.  (Or that there was no consensus, if that's what happened.)

Comment: Do we want to post the summaries here so they are easily accessible?

Comment: @James Putting them in both places would probably be the *most* accessible

Comment: @James I'd say summaries of each question set on those questions, and then as overall patterns start to emerge, answers here should talk about those patterns. At that point it's not about Tim's or your or HDE's (etc) questions but about certain *types* of questions.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I volunteer too.  Don't schedule me on a Saturday; other than that, do whatever works.

Comment: @monicacellio makes sense to me.

Comment: I volunteer too. Just don't schedule me for weekends please

Comment: I could fill in on the Saturday (Feb 20).

Comment: I would like to contribute, as I am curious about how the community percieves my posts. But I only have one question. So I wanted to know, whether I would be fine to post it (maybe as an extra someday?) or whether a +7 question has not enough significance for this discussion

Comment: Right now, we have 10 volunteers. If each provide 5 questions, we get 50 questions. That's probably enough to get some discussion going, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin alright. I was just curious, that's why I asked

Comment: @T3H40, my remark wasn't addressed to you directly. I generally do think we have enough material to get started. If you think that one or more of your questions really bring a new light to the discussion, you're welcome to add them, maybe in comments here, or drop by the [chat].

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin I guess it wouldn't add much to the discussion in general. I totally agree with you on that. I will delete my comments, as they are obsolete now :)

Comment: @T3H40, don't. That way, we will know where to look for if we need more material :-)

Comment: Can you sign me up for March 15? Or do you need it earlier?

Comment: I'd like to volunteer for this. Some questions I've written or been involved in make interesting case studies, and may help us clarify our scope yet further.

Comment: @fi12 you can go ahead and post whenever you want to, at the moment there's no one else scheduled

Comment: @CAgrippa sure, you can post a case study, I just ask that you wait for fi12 to go first, and give it a couple of days for people to look at his cases first

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh OK, great. I'll start drafting soon. The interesting one of course is the big religion thing, but there are some others here and there.

Comment: How do I sign up to do one of these?