# Case Studies - Green's Highest Viewed Questions

Tags: discussion, on-topic, case-study

[What would it take to build a ship capable of crossing the Pacific?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25272/what-would-it-take-to-build-a-ship-capable-of-crossing-the-pacific)

**About Worldbuilding?**  This question asks if building a trans-Pacific ship is feasible using only merchants as the shipbuilders. (They die horribly in one way or another.)

**Off topic?** Nope.

**Idea Generation**  Not IG since the question asks for a binary Yes/No with some justification.  IG tends to generate open ended lists.

---

[What good are herbivores in an animal army?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25724/what-good-are-herbivores-in-an-animal-army)

**About Worldbuilding?** Yes.

**Off topic?** No.  A fantasy world of human style conflict but carried out by carnivores and herbivores is definitely worldbuilding.

**Idea Generation** No, since the question outlines a set of constraints for the answer.

---

[How to defend against the “convince-me” ray gun?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26991/how-to-defend-against-the-convince-me-ray-gun)

**About Worldbuilding?**  Yes.  The question focuses on a world mechanic involving a semi-involuntary mind control/idea implantation at a distance.

**Off topic?**  I don't think so.  Mind control ray guns seems very world-builder-y to me.

**Idea Generation** No, because there were sufficient constraints to limit the answers and decide a "best" answer.

---

[How do you find a mate when everyone looks amazing?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21142/how-do-you-find-a-mate-when-everyone-looks-amazing)

**About Worldbuilding?**  Yes.  The question asks for a description of specific adaptations or sociological systems that would influence how a person goes about finding a mate when personal appearance is no longer fixed.

**Off topic?**  No.  Genetic manipulation of appearance is definitely on topic.

**Idea Generation** Likely not.  Though this question can generate a list of possible fitness criteria,

---

[What is the best apex predator to thin the zombie herds?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23192/what-is-the-best-apex-predator-to-thin-the-zombie-herds)

**About Worldbuilding?**  Yes.  The question addresses natural ecosystems after most humans turn to zombies with respect to apex predators.  Asking about the *entire ecosystem* would have been too broad.

**Off topic?**  No.  A world of zombies is definitely WB material.

**Idea Generation** Edgy. The question asks for "the best" apex predator to thin the zombie herds but doesn't really specify any criteria for what constitutes "best".

Answer (score 1):

**What would it take to build a ship capable of crossing the Pacific?**

Yes, No, This definitely fits the risk profile for what if but I believe this one is properly developed and constrained to be on-topic.

**What good are herbivores in an animal army?**

Yes, No, Seems defined enough to me.

**How to defend against the “convince-me” ray gun?**

Yes, No, It is idea generation but the question has many constraints so finding a best answer seems doable.

**How do you find a mate when everyone looks amazing?**

Sort of, I think so, Yep...so the problem is that the gene augmentation/editing isn't really the question, the question seems to be more a general discussion of how appearance impacts mate selection when removed from the equation.  Which while an interesting question I don't think really fits here.