# Case Study #6 - HDE 226868

Tags: discussion, on-topic, case-study

Part of [the case study series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3048/case-study-series?rq=1).

[Can stars exist that are not powered by nuclear fusion?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22769/can-stars-exist-that-are-not-powered-by-nuclear-fusion)

**About worldbuilding?** I would say yes, because whether or not this is possible is the key to the premise of my world (an artificial star). It is certainly strongly based in science, but I think that's okay. After all, I want my world to be believable.

**Risking off-topic?** I would say not. It's broad-ish, but a lot of the answers said that it wasn't possible, for various reasons, so maybe it's straightforward.

[How would a war between immortals be fought?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25658/how-would-a-war-between-immortals-be-fought)

**About worldbuilding?** Yes, as it defines tactics in a conflict that will impact the entire world (in this case, one nation).

**Risking off-topic?** Possibly too broad, and it does focus on the actions of individuals - and there are a lot of possibilities, as evidenced by all the answers it got. So maybe this one's closeable.

[Could an average person take over the world?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23350/could-an-average-person-take-over-the-world)

**About worldbuilding?** Yes; the actions of this person will shape the fate of the entire world.

**Risking off-topic?** Well, it's currently closed, and one of the close voters was me. I think it's really too broad as it stands; there are loads of possibilities.

[How can I make my languages structurally less like English?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23765/how-can-i-make-my-languages-structurally-less-like-english)

**About worldbuilding?** Heck yes.

**Risking off-topic?** Again, this one could be too broad, but it's broader than most [worldbuilding-process](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-process) questions, in my opinion. I think it's fine.

[How would government change if everyone died by the age of 25?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29199/how-would-government-change-if-everyone-died-by-the-age-of-25)

**About worldbuilding?** Yes.

**Risking off-topic?** It's similar to a What-if? question, but it *does* set guidelines and explain what I've considered, as well as the background. It also focuses only on small part of my world.

Answer (score 1):

Non fusion stars: On topic

Immortal wars: Subject is fine but too broad

Average Joe: Too broad. Subject is ok since it's "can" not "should" or "would".

Language structures: On topic.

25: On topic.