# Case Study #7 - Aify

Tags: discussion, on-topic, case-study

Part of [the case study series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3048/case-study-series?rq=1).

[Lets weaponize jellyfish](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18402/lets-weaponize-jellyfish)

**About worldbuilding?** Yes, because I had already provided the hypothetical world - the purpose of the question was to use the basis of that world to weaponize something for the entire hypothetical world to use.

**Risking off-topic?** Possibly risking Idea Generation, but I think enough restrictions were provided in the question to allow for a objective view on best answer.

[What are the conditions in which a creature would evolve more than one brain?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14807/what-are-the-conditions-in-which-a-creature-would-evolve-more-than-one-brain)

**About worldbuilding?** Yes - this question could be referenced for future creature design of anyone who wants to have a world of creatures with 2 brains.

**Risking off-topic?** Again, possibly Idea Generation, but I think that enough restriction was given on the definition of "2 brains".

[Why would the mouth of a creature evolve to be away from the head?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28191/why-would-the-mouth-of-a-creature-evolve-to-be-away-from-the-head)

**About worldbuilding?** Same theory as the two brains question, so yes.

**Risking off-topic?** Nope. This one definitely has more than enough detail keeping it away from "Too Broad", and the details and pictures depict exactly what I'm saying/mean, so even Idea Generation is limited severely by the requirement to fit the provided pictures + description.

[Projectile Weaponization of Water](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17498/projectile-weaponization-of-water)

**About worldbuilding?** Yes, as it applies to any world that could use a projectile water weapon, which happens to be almost any hypothetical world with water.

**Risking off-topic?** Restrictions provided stop it from being too broad/idea generation, so no.

[Sea creature moving via rotational motions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15278/sea-creature-moving-via-rotational-motions)

**About worldbuilding?** Yes, for essentially the same reason as the above 2 creature design questions.

**Risking off-topic?** Maybe too broad/opinion based. I probably didn't provide enough restrictions for this one. Luckily, since the majority of the answers were "not possible" answers, it was easy for me to pick the one answer that **did** actually answer the question properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Weaponized Jellyfish** I agree this is pushing into idea generation territory but overall it's in pretty good shape.

**Multiple brains** Again risking idea generation, and that's supported by the number of questions in the comments. Overall I agree it's the right side of the line though.

**Non-head mouth** Same as the others, you seem to ask a lot of interesting worldbuilding questions that are all pushing into idea generation but staying the right side of the line.

**Weaponized Water** Same as the others.

**Rotational Sea Motion** Same as the others.