# Case Study: Monica Cellio

Tags: discussion, on-topic, case-study

Part of [Case study series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3048/case-study-series).

(Whoops -- just noticed I missed my assigned date.  Sorry.)

[In space, do "shipping lanes" make sense?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/16/in-space-do-shipping-lanes-make-sense)

**About worldbuilding?** Yes, it's about travel patterns and thus, indirectly, "layout" of points of interest in space.

**Risking off-topic?** I think it's on-topic, though one could argue that I needed to specify a tech level rather than hand-waving that.  I think that's ok because sometimes worldbuilding runs backwards -- I have this outcome, and I'll make the background lead to that.

[How would having multiple moons affect tides?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/71/how-would-having-multiple-moons-affect-tides)

**About worldbuilding?** Yes.  The effects of planetary/lunar/solar configurations are well within our scope and we have many such questions.

**Risking off-topic?** No, I think this question is on pretty firm ground.

[How quickly and accurately should news travel in a rural medieval setting?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13/how-quickly-and-accurately-should-news-travel-in-a-rural-medieval-setting)

**About worldbuilding?** It's about communities' behavior in a world -- travel, fragmentation, interactions with outsiders.  It could have been asked more cleanly, and the original version was in retrospect off-topic as a history question.

**Risking off-topic?** It's still a history question at heart and is kind of broad and speculative, though I tried to fix that in a later edit.

[Must magic be tied to medieval tech?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/8/must-magic-be-tied-to-medieval-tech)

**About worldbuilding?** It's about the relation between magic and technology, both of which are core worldbuilding factors, so yes.

**Risking off-topic?** But it's pretty opinion-based and speculative.  It's more a philosophy question than a concrete worldbuilding question.  Were it asked now I think it would be closed.  (That was, I think, Day 2 of private beta.)

[What are the necessary conditions for a worldwide government?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-are-the-necessary-conditions-for-a-worldwide-government)

**About worldbuilding?** Government is part of worlds and this is about developing government, so I say yes.

**Risking off-topic?** I think it's on-topic.  It describes a desired outcome, suggests one way to possibly get there, and asks about alternatives to that.  It draws some precedents from our world to provide some foundation.

Answer (score 4):

[In space, do "shipping lanes" make sense?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/16/in-space-do-shipping-lanes-make-sense)

**About worldbuilding?** Yes, this is about building a world.  How will x work in the future given y scenario.

**Risking off-topic?** No, this one seems pretty clear to me.

[How would having multiple moons affect tides?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/71/how-would-having-multiple-moons-affect-tides)

**About worldbuilding?** Yes, clearly on topic...though if we don't want to continue answering how does this planetary set up work questions maybe we create some sort of guide for people to use...though that's a lot of math and I would have trouble following personally.

**Risking off-topic?** Clearly On Topic.

[How quickly and accurately should news travel in a rural medieval setting?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13/how-quickly-and-accurately-should-news-travel-in-a-rural-medieval-setting)

**About worldbuilding?** Clearly about building a world.  Trying to understand and define how things work.

**Risking off-topic?** History questions, like physics, biology etc are a discussion we need to have...do we want them here?  If we want them fine...but we should discuss there seems to be plenty of confusion around that.

[Must magic be tied to medieval tech?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/8/must-magic-be-tied-to-medieval-tech)

**About worldbuilding?** Again yes about world building but maybe not a great fit.

**Risking off-topic?** I concur this one is very opinion based, I don't know that we can objectively say why medieval settings are more predominant when it comes to magic...though I think I could answer that.  I actually think the larger problem is the comparison of modern versus medieval...yeah this one would be closed.

[What are the necessary conditions for a worldwide government?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-are-the-necessary-conditions-for-a-worldwide-government)

**About worldbuilding?** Developing nations and their governments is clearly on topic.

**Risking off-topic?** I would say clearly on-topic.  There is a ton of historical information to base an answer on.

Comment: These opinions are now my opinions. Anything I would have said is included here, as well as things I had not considered but agree with. Thus, there is no need for me to write my own answer (though I want to point out that I considered it).

Comment: It might be worth starting a meta post to ask about History questions - or proposing it as a Risk Factor on that post http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3206/worldbuilding-scope-risk-factors

Answer (score 2):

Shipping Lanes: On topic

Multiple Moons: On topic

Medieval News: On topic unless we decide history questions are off topic. Personally I think they're fine but I know some people disagree.

Medieval Magic: I sort of agree, this could be closed as too opinion based if asked now. On the other hand a definitive "no" answer with reasons can be given so maybe it's ok.

Worldwide Government: It could be quite broad, but I think it's ok.